# Generate list from other 2 lists by repeating - looking for a built-in function

Tags: python

Given:

```py
date_range = ['2022-05-27','2022-05-28']
hour_range = [0,2,4,6]
```

I want to generate:

```py
[
    ('2022-05-27',0),
    ('2022-05-27',2),
    ('2022-05-27',4),
    ('2022-05-27',6),
    ('2022-05-28',0),
    ('2022-05-28',2),
    ('2022-05-28',4),
    ('2022-05-28',6),
]
```

I tried `zip()`, `map()`, etc. which doesnt exactly get the expected output. What built-in function can I use to avoid writing multiple loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product
list(product(date_range, hour_range))
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 ('2022-05-27', 0), ('2022-05-27', 2), ('2022-05-27', 4), ('2022-05-27', 6), 
 ('2022-05-28', 0), ('2022-05-28', 2), ('2022-05-28', 4), ('2022-05-28', 6)
]
```